# Disable event listener

Tags: .net, wpf

Here's my xaml:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid Name="ButtonLayer"/>
 <Canvas Name="Overlay"/>
</Grid>
```

Here's my problem:

I have buttons in the ButtonLayer and a polyline in the Overlay Canvas. I wan't to disable all mouse events for the Overlay canvas so that the buttons in the ButtonLayer can receive mouse input. How to do it without moving the Overlay below the ButtonLayer (because then the Overlay is covered by the ButtonLayer)?

Comment: It sounds to me like your "Overlay" layer should be an adorner to your `Grid`.  You should consider doing that and use adorners.

Comment: look at the answer from @RV1987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `IsHitTestVisible=False` on the Canvas. Events will pass through to your grid.

```
<Canvas Name="Overlay" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
```